# Jupyter NB cell within dataproc cluster (PySpark) shows executing for more than an hour now, how do i check if the job is running or not?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

Below is the code i'm using to write output df to BigQuery from PySpark cluster(dataproc). While running this earlier i was getting heartbeat timeout issue, fixed that. Then i was getting executor memory overhead exceeded, increased that. Now, this chunk of code it running for unlimited time and in the log it shows
`2020-06-12 02:55:45.395 IST Cache Size Before Clean: 34922812, Total Deleted: 0, Public Deleted: 0, Private Deleted: 0`. What should i understand from it? Is it running or not? If it's not running then what is the solution?

```
output.write \
      .format("bigquery") \
      .option("table","{}.{}".format(bq_dataset, bq_table)) \
      .option("temporaryGcsBucket", gcs_bucket) \
      .mode('append') \
      .save()
```

Comment: Do you have more details on the size of the data and the cluster size you are using? Are the files being written to GCS?